# Authenticating a user at login using OAuth2 without additional consent

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Marketplace app that is currently using OpenID for federated login.

When an admin installs the application to the domain users are able to login via a site.com/login/domain.com link.

Currently when a user uses this link they are being asked to consent once again for "Know who you are on Google" scope. I understand that this is something to do with my OpenID realm not matching. The problem is I cannot find where to edit that realm in the new console. My research shows that OpenID has been abandoned for OAuth2 authentication. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there a good example anywhere that shows how to authenticate a user that an admin has already granted scopes for on the domain so that they **do not get asked to consent again**? I've looked up and seen documentation to make a call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth but I'm unaware of how to actually skip the user consent since the admin already authorized the scopes domain-wide.

Using C# but I'm open to any example as I'm sure I can figure out how to get it back into C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/oauth2-dev/p8am51gyrns) on the google groups, then it seems it is intentionally :

> This is an intentional change to more precisely communicate to users
>   the set of permissions that is being granted. Through knowledge of the
>   user's email address it is possible, via indirect means, to locate the
>   user's profile address. In the interest of more accurate disclosure,
>   thus, we are prompting users to approve such disclosure.
>
> The new tokens issued include permissions to obtain public profile
>   information, in accordance with the modified text. You can use
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall
>   to obtain the subset of user's profile information that is publicly
>   linked from the user's profile. The user's profile Id, which is always
>   public in that endpoint, is also a more reliable identifier for the
>   user (as email addresses can be changed on accounts). We recommend
>   that you store the user's profile id to ensure that email changes
>   don't cause account confusion.

Comment: Thanks. This is the exact opposite of the previous documentation which  implied that the most seamless user experience was desired. Strange...